# iMacros help, Recording information using iMacros on Firefox

Tags: firefox, record, imacros, gambling

if i was scripting on a text based game, continuously betting on Roulette, would there be any way to record the numbers that come up?
or record the mot frequent number?

Comment: Please visit [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

If the text based game can run in a Internet Browser, you could try to extract information with iMacros.

- Use [SAVEAS](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) and save to a .CSV
- Run the script
- Find out the [most common number in a group of numbers](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-group-of-numbers-HA010070504.aspx) (Excel)

Answer (score 0):

You could always take screenshots? But that would add up quickly :P
http://wiki.imacros.net/SCREENSHOT